# Showing linear independence when indexing set is a subset of a product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Suppose $R$ is a ring and $M$ a left module over $R$. Let $(m_j)_{j\in J}$ be a free family of $M$. Suppose $\sum_{(i,j)\in K}r_im_j=0$, where $K\subset I\times J$ for some set $I$ and the set $\{(i,j)\in K\ |\ r_im_j\ne0\}$ is finite.

How can I show that $\sum_{(i,j)\in K}r_im_j=0$ implies $r_i=0$ for all $i\in\text{pr}_1(K)$? The problem here is that the coefficients and the free elements are indexed by different sets. This doesn't occur in the case where we have something like $\sum_{j\in J}a_j m_j$.

Writing $(e_j)_{j\in J}$ for the canonical basis of $R^{(J)}$, the fact that $(m_j)_{j\in J}$ is free means that the canonical $R$-homomorphism
$f:R^{(J)}\rightarrow M$ such that $f(e_j)=m_j$ for all $j$ is injective. How can I formulate the problem above in terms of proving the injectivity of a canonical linear map?

How to proceed here?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing something, but I do not think that what you try to prove actually holds.

With $J$ arbitrary, $J_0 \subseteq J$ finite, $I = \{1,2\}$, $K = I \times J_0$ and $r_1 = 1$ as well as $r_2 = -1$ you will get
$$ \sum_{(i,j) \in K}r_i m_j = \sum_{j} (1 \cdot m_j + (-1) \cdot m_j) = 0. $$